# Сопоставить несколько URL через regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения, сопоставление-с-образцом

Всем привет.
Есть два path:

```
/api/test/{path param}
/api/test/{path param}/full
```

Мне нужно сопоставить URL на который сервер прислал запрос с этими двумя путями.

Регулярки для этого я использовал следующие:

```
\/test\/.*
\/test\/.*\/full
```

Но сразу возникла проблема. Второй путь маппится на обе регулярки, т.к. первой регулярке без разницы, что будет после /test/.
Соответственно возникает запрос на то, чтобы как-то проверять второй случай, отсекая первую регулярку.

Из идей, это добавить в регулярку заканчивающуюся на ".*" проверку на то, что во всех этих символах не будет содержаться '/'.

```
\/test\/.* но не '/' в конечной группе
```

Но я не совсем понимаю, как это можно сделать.
Пробовал такую регулярку:

```
\/test\/[^\/]+
```

Но она все равно матчит первый кейс по **/test/1**/full. И только если сделать такой путь /test//full, то матча не будет.

Answer (score 0):

**Первый урл будет матчить регулярное [выражение](https://regex101.com/r/hJBX7b/1):**

```
^/api/test/.+(?<!/full)$
```

Подробности о [Negative Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

**Для второго урла:**

```
^/api/test/.+/full$
```

Comment: Для второго урла все круто. Похожий подход использовал и я, только ошибся добавив * вместо +.
А вот с первым я не совсем уверен. Первый матчит любые пути, которые не содержат /full в конце. Это не было бы проблемой, если бы этих путей было ровно два. Предположим у меня есть путь, который заканчивается на '/less'. Он сматчится с этой регуляркой. Можно ли сделать как-то так, чтобы на привязываться к full?
Я читал, что negative lookbehind не поддерживает '.*'.

Comment: я дал ссылку на песочницу https://regex101.com/r/hJBX7b/1 Поиграйтесь